# How to cal another function within an object function

Tags: javascript, object

How can I call another function from a function within an object in JavaScript.

For example, I'm trying to do this:

```
var mydiv1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
var mydiv2 = document.querySelector('.div2');

var myVariable1;
var myVariable2;

var myObject = (function() {
    return {
        function1 : function (myVariable1) {
            myVariable2 = "this was called from a function and inserted by function2";
            mydiv1.innerHTML = myVariable1;
            function2(myVariable2);
        },

        function2 : function (myVariable2) {
            mydiv2.innerHTML = myVariable2;
        }
    };

}());

mydiv1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myVariable1 = "this was called from a function and inserted by function1";
    myVariable2 = "this was called from a function and inserted by function2";
    myObject.function1(myVariable1);
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kvtxd/6/

"Function1" runs as excepted, but I get an error that function2 is undefined. What's the correct way do do this?

The reason I'm using an object is so that I can call each internal function individually if needed. I.e just call function2 but not function1.

See, If I use:

```
function WholeFunction() {
   function function1() {
   //   
   }
   function function2() {
   //   
   }
}
```

Then function1 and function2 are out of scope and I can only call the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "this" keyword when inside a function:

```
function1 : function (myVariable1) {
            myVariable2 = "this was called from a function and inserted by function2";
            mydiv1.innerHTML = myVariable1;
            this.function2(myVariable2); // use "this" here!!!!
        },
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YDhK6/)

Comment: It's always the small things!

Comment: Does "this" refer to the the object, variable, or to the function?

Comment: @user3143218: `this` refers to the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can access attributes of the same object using `this`. I added it to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kvtxd/8/